# Apache - Allow one wildcard URL, deny all other requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, httpd.conf

On Apache, how do I allow only traffic from one wildcard URL, such as: ****secure.mywebsite.com****, and DENY all other http requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !(^|\.)secure\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This will deny (forbidden error) all the web requests if they're not for `secure.mywebsite.com`

Comment: Thank you. Need I enable (unhash) any modules to enable/add this?

Comment: Yes `mod_rewrite` needs to be enabled and `.htaccess` should be enabled too.

Comment: ok cool thank you. One more thing - secure\.mywebsite\.com, is it for this address explicitly or will this work for example: something.secure.mywebsite.com/home/index.php ?

Comment: Since I am using `^` before `secure` therefore my regex will only match (and allow) `secure.mywebsite.com`. If your requirement is to allow `something.secure.mywebsite.com` also, please let me know, I will change the regex above.

Comment: Isn't htaccess enabled by default? Not sure what you mean by: .htaccess should be enabled too

Comment: Usually it is enabled but in some rare cases I have seen it is disabled initially that's why I mentioned.

Comment: OK thanks. Then, will this work for frontend.secure.mywebsite.com/home/index as well? (just an example address), so is this a wildcard match?

Comment: Made a small edit, now it will allow `frontend.secure.mywebsite.com/home/index` or `anything.secure.mywebsite.com/home/index`